# Why are attachments not showing up in emails sent with Mimekit?

Tags: c#, winforms, mimekit

*Edit*
The message.writeto() created the email exactly as expected, with file attached. it's just not showing up like that in outlook.

i'll keep it short. i'm trying to send an email from winforms using MimeKit, and have opted for the builder approach after getting a parse error when manually attempting to code the filestream.

So, what i've tried:

Public string as the "filepath"

```
        public string ReturnAttachment1
        {
            get { return attachment1; }
            set { attachment1 = value; }
        }
```

Event for open file Dialog:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
                openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
                openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    ReturnAttachment1 = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    textBox19.Text = ReturnAttachment1.ToString();
                    //Note: textBox19 correctly displays filepath string
                }
            }    
        }
```

Then inside the message creation:

```
            TextPart body1 = new TextPart("html")
            {
                Text = @"Please See Below Information" + "<br/>" +
                      "<h4>Return ID: " + "  " + Returnid + "</h4>" + "<br/>" +
                      "<b>Fabricator Name:</b>" + "  " + Fname + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine +
                      "<b>Account Number:</b>" + "  " + Facc + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine +
                      "<b>Address Line 1:</b>" + "  " + Fadd1 + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine +
                      "<b>Address Line 2:</b>" + "  " + Fadd2 + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine +
                      "<b>Town:</b>" + "  " + Ftown + "<br/> " + Environment.NewLine +
                      "<b>County:</b>" + "  " + Fcounty + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine +
                      "<b>Postcode:</b>" + "  " + Fpostcode + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine +
                      "<b>Phone:</b>" + "  " + Fphoneno + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine +
                      "<b>Email:</b>" + "  " + Femail + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine + "<br/>" +
                      "<br/>" +

                      "<b>Invoice: </b>" + "  " + Inv + "<br/>" +
                      "<b>Material Information:</b>" + "<br/>" +
                      //slab 1
                      "<b>Thickness: </b>" + "  " + Thick1 + "mm" + "<br/>" +
                      "<b>Material Name: </b>" + "  " + Material1 + "<br/>" +
                      "<b>Batch No: </b>" + "  " + Batch1 + "<br/>" +
                      "<b>Reason for Return: </b>" + "  " + Reason1 + "<br/>" +
                      "<br/>" +
                      "<b>Notes:" + "  " + Notes
            };

            //check for return attachment and if found, assign attachment to message via MultiPart()
            if (ReturnAttachment1.Length > 7)
            {
                var builder = new BodyBuilder();
                builder.TextBody = body1.Text;
                builder.HtmlBody = body1.Text;
                builder.Attachments.Add(ReturnAttachment1.ToString());

                //now set the multipart mixed as the message body
                message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
            }
            else
            {
                message.Body = body1;
            }
                //Connection to SMTP and Criteria to Send
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

                client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate("notthatstupid@notthisaddress.com", "notthispassword");

                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);

            }
        }
```

Now.. The email sends perfectly fine, but for some reason, no attachments are being added to the email, and no exceptions or errors are occuring that show up on debug.

Is anyone able to assist please?

Comment: There is an if condition which checks that the length of the ReturnAttachment1 is greater that 7. Why are you doing this? If the path length happens to be less than 7 it won't add the attachment. Better check for null value.

Comment: What's with the `ToString()` calls on something that *is already a string*?

Comment: look i'm a complete begginer, i'm sure i'll pick it up as i go along, i'm just putting into to practice what i've learnt in my own retarded little way.

how about why it isn't attaching though?

Comment: We can't debug fragments of code. You're somehow sure you've picked out the right fragments to show us but, by definition, you don't know where the problem is. You need to learn about creating a [mcve].

Comment: Try saving the message to a local file to take a look at the raw MIME. To do that, use `message.WriteTo ("message.eml");`

Comment: hi jstedfast, 

I've done what you said, navigated to the repo location and found the message.eml, 

The email file looks complete, with my file attached!!! :-D
its strange why they're not attaching in the actual emails though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was an idiot and left a line of code in that changed the message body.

this question is now redundant.

Thanks to Jstedfast, this helped me to find it fast :-)